# Javascript/jquery refresh only 5 second by loading first time

Tags: javascript, jquery

javascript/jquery refresh 5 second by loading first time. i have a page content data filtered that comes from another page so must refresh menualy 4/5 time in order to get content filtered. Is there anyway when page loads, set 5 second waiting time so this 5 second reload page every 1 second. 
Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: I'm not clear on what you want. Would you like to wait 5 seconds initially, then after those 5 seconds reload the page every second?

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean something like this:

It uses localstorage to store the refresh amount..

```
var myInterval = setInterval(function ()
{
    var i;

    if(isNaN(localStorage.getItem("reloadNumber")))
    {
       i = 0;
    }
    else
    {
       i = parseInt(localStorage.getItem("reloadNumber"));
    }

    i++;

    localStorage.setItem("reloadNumber", i);

    if (i >= 5)
    {
       clearInterval(myInterval);
    }
    else
    {
         window.location.reload();
    }

}, 1000);
```